# Configuring routing in Juniper router

Tags: routing, juniper, junos

I have a Juniper SRX220 (junos) router where I have configured vlan.1 and vlan.2 with IP 10.0.1.1/24 and 10.0.2.1/24. 
Now I want to route between these networks. How do I configure that in Junos? I can't figure that out from the manual and it does not work out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this is an SRX, there are a number of requirements here.

Step 1:

Define VLANS (think layer 2)

```
set vlans vlan1 description desktops vlan-id 1 l3-interface vlan.1

set vlans vlan2 description servers vlan-id 2 l3-interface vlan.2
```

Step 2:

Define L3 interfaces bound to those vlans...

```
set interfaces vlan unit 1 family inet address 10.0.1.1/24

set interfaces vlan unit 2 family inet addresses 10.0.2.1/24
```

Step 3:

Place those L3 interfaces into a zone

```
set security zones security-zone trust interfaces vlan.1

set security zones security-zone trust interfaces vlan.2
```

Step 4:

Since this is an SRX, you must create a policy permitting intra-zone traffic

```
set security policies from-zone trust to-zone trust policy trust-to-trust match source-address any destination-address any application any then permit
```

Step 5:

Set physical interfaces onto that VLAN

```
set interfaces ge-0/0/0 unit 0 family ethernet switching port-mode access vlan members vlan1

set interfaces ge-0/0/1 unit 0 family ethernet switching port-mode access vlan members vlan2
```

Step 6:

Plug devices in. Once any interface assigned to that VLAN is physically up, the VLAN interface for that VLAN will come up.

Comment: Thanks a million! It was step 4 and step 5 that was missing in my configuration.

Comment: If you are going to use this device as just a router, you can change the default action to permit instead of drop, FYI.